# Localised events - closing after time?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

We have a few events like the Egypt riots, the [Prague flooding](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17971/how-bad-is-the-prague-flooding) and more, which have questions on them.

However, these obviously are no longer relevant after a period of time.

Should we decide on a mandate to close them after a certain period? Or somehow make it really clear which Prague flooding we're talking about, for future viewers of the site?

Comment: Ah, the old downvote without explanation. On Meta.  The most pointless action of all.

Comment: Obviously someone who asks these kind of questions :)

Answer (score 4):

First, yeah, it should be made clear which particular event the post refers to. When it's current, there's no possibility for confusion, but otherwise at least some indication when is helpful.

Apart from that, the easiest way is probably just flagging them with a custom reason and explain. A month or two after the event seems somewhat reasonable period to wait before closure.

I'm tempted to suggest a tag for them to find them quickly, but it's probably going to be a meta one, which is somewhat frowned upon.

Comment: yeah, [tag:old-events] or something. But it's very meta :/

Comment: how about "expired"?